# how do get a duplicate count with a duplicate value in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get duplicate count with duplicate value in ASP.NET C#,
so, I don't need SQL part because I use data in buil on the background

Example:

I have below data,

| ID | Size |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000984958 | XS | ---Different ID different size (ID count 1) |
| 1000972994 | S | ---Same ID different size (ID count 2) |
| 1000972994 | L | ---Same ID different size (ID count 2) |

Result:

| ID | Size | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000984958 | XS | 1 |
| 1000972994 | S | 2 |
| 1000972994 | L | 2 |

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count the duplicate items in your collection you can use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/). For example in your case you can group you list by ID and count the number of element in this list.

For example :

```
var q = from x in tb
        group x by x.ID into g
        let count = g.Count()
        orderby count descending
        select new { Value = g.Key, Count = count };
```

OR

```
var q = tb.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
            .Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
```

Working console application is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<MyClass> tb = new List<MyClass>
            {
                new MyClass {ID =1000984958, Size = "XS", IdCount = 1 },
                new MyClass {ID = 1000972994, Size = "S", IdCount = 2},
                new MyClass {ID= 1000972994, Size = "L", IdCount =  2 },
                new MyClass {ID= 1000991726, Size = "S", IdCount =  3 },
                new MyClass {ID= 1000991726, Size = "M", IdCount =  3 },
                new MyClass {ID= 1000991726, Size = "L", IdCount =  3 },
                new MyClass {ID= 1000980092, Size = "M", IdCount =  1 },
            };

            var q = from x in tb
                    group x by x.ID into g
                    let count = g.Count()
                    orderby count descending
                    select new { Value = g.Key, Count = count };

            foreach (var x in q)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Value: " + x.Value + " Count: " + x.Count);
            }
        }
    }
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
        public int IdCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image: output of duplicate count in console app.]

Comment: Thank you, Kiran, But I Need duplicate values... 
I need the below result can you help me, please 

ID  | Size | Id Count
1000984958 |  XS |    1
1000972994 |  S |    2
1000972994 |  L |    2
1000991726 |  S |    1

Comment: @DanushkaFernando what do you mean? Do we need to check size and ID both?

Comment: No, I need a duplicate count for each row 


Example:

I have below data,

ID  | Size |
1000984958 |  XS |---Different ID different size (ID count 1)
1000972994 |  S |---Same ID different size (ID count 2)
1000972994 |  L |---Same ID different size (ID count 2)

Result:

ID  | Size | Count
1000984958 |  XS |    1
1000972994 |  S |    2
1000972994 |  L |    2

Comment: @DanushkaFernando do you mean something like this.
Dictionary<int, int> q = tb.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
            .Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).ToDictionary( x=> x.Value, x => x.Count);

            foreach (var x in tb)
            {
    Console.WriteLine("ID: " +x.ID+ "Size: " +x.Size+ " Count:" +q[x.ID]);
            }

Comment: @DanushkaFernando replace var q = from x in tb
                    group x by x.ID into g
                    let count = g.Count()
                    orderby count descending
                    select new { Value = g.Key, Count = count };

            foreach (var x in q)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Value: " + x.Value + " Count: " + x.Count);
            } with above code

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nf2Ifp